# For baking with the ledger, what should I set the high watermark to?

Tags: node, tezos-client, ledger

For baking with the ledger, what should I set the high watermark? Should it be zero? I can't find any good explanation for what is watermark. Is it the current block level?

Comment: Why isn't the software smart enough to prevent double bake without this?

Answer (score 3):

High watermark is the lowest block number that your ledger is allowed to sign bake or endorse operations. That means if the watermark is set to `100000`, the ledger is disallowed to sign any block number `100000` or below. This is a mechanism to prevent [double baking](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-is-the-penalty-for-double-baking).

The [ledger-app documentation](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos#reset-high-watermark) states:

> When updating the version of Tezos Baking you are using or if you are
>   switching baking to a new ledger device, we recommend setting the HWM (high watermark)
>   to the current head block level of the blockchain.

This will prevent you from double signing a previously bake or endorse operation which will lead to getting penalized. I recommend reading more details in the [tezos ledger app documentation](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos).

Comment: You wrote "cycle" but I think you meant "block".

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but high water mark is useful in order to minimize any risk of double baking/endorsing.

Answer (score 0):

Talking to some people at the meetup tonight.  You should set the watermark to the nearest block, then input that with your ledger so it isn't trying to confirm previous blocks.  I'll update this question if the new firmware on the nano s had something to do with this problem.