# Debug of missed an endorsement

Tags: kiln, endorser

Is it possible to read why Kiln missed an endorsement? There is any possibility to debug such kind of situation?

```
Apr 04 15:46:18 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 15:46:18 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement: Error while injecting endorsement for delegate tz1QHd5o2iqqEigkUwK4QGJvuNRfhz2eY1xh : 
    Apr 04 15:46:18 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 15:46:18 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement:   Error:
    Apr 04 15:46:18 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 15:46:18 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement:     Found no ledger corresponding to ledger://amused-havanese-tedious-robin/ed25519/0h/0h.
    Apr 04 15:46:18 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 15:46:18 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement: 
    Apr 04 15:46:18 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 15:46:18 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement: 
    Apr 04 17:56:39 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 17:56:39 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement: Error while injecting endorsement for delegate tz1QHd5o2iqqEigkUwK4QGJvuNRfhz2eY1xh : 
    Apr 04 17:56:39 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 17:56:39 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement:   Error:
    Apr 04 17:56:39 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 17:56:39 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement:     Found no ledger corresponding to ledger://amused-havanese-tedious-robin/ed25519/0h/0h.
    Apr 04 17:56:39 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 17:56:39 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement: 
    Apr 04 17:56:39 kiln-endorser[1851]: Apr  4 17:56:39 - 006-PsCARTHA.baking.endorsement: 
    -- Reboot --
```

Comment: Honestly, do you not see the plain-as-day error message `Error: Found no ledger corresponding to ledger://....`? Kiln missed endorsement because it could not communicate with your ledger.

Comment: But there was access, I think, how to be sure that Kiln has access to Ledger? There is any variable, logs to know it before endorsement, not after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on reports from community members, the most effective way to repair the connection between Kiln and the Ledger device is to remove the baker from Kiln using the baker tile's menu, then re-add the baker. If you'd like to try signing something before taking this step, I recommend setting the highwater mark or re-authorizing the Ledger device, also from the baker tile's menu.

With the information provided, this is the best guidance I can give at this time. Note that this advice is most targeted towards someone who isn't baking or endorsing at all - not someone who has intermittent issues.

Some additional notes worth considering:

- I've most commonly heard of this issue appearing after voting. In those cases, removing and re-adding the baker has proven effective
- Using the Ledger-provided cable has also proven to have an impact. Not that other cables do not work, but these have proven to be the most reliable
- It is possible for the Ledger cable, like any other, to break down over time and stop working. This actually happened to me just last week!
- Make sure you have covered other steps you can use to either inspect or reset communication, such as restarting the machine or running `lsusb` to show connected USB devices

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Could you say or link to docs regarding "highwater mark", what is it, how it works, etc.?

Comment: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/for-baking-with-the-ledger-what-should-i-set-the-high-watermark-to

Comment: But the way, is it possible to check BEFORE endorsing blocks connectivity between Kiln and Ledger?